# How to make a GET request using the NetworkStream class?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, http

I am trying to make a GET request using the NetworkStream class.  MyWebServer does not log the request so I am assumming that request is not formatted properly.

```
 public void MakeRequest()
    {
        int port = 80;
        IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("192.168.1.152");
        IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint(host.AddressList[0], 80);

        using (Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp))
        {
            socket.Connect(endPoint);

            using (NetworkStream ns = new NetworkStream(socket))
            {
                byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"GET /MyWebServer HTTP/1.1\r\n");
                ns.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't need to use `Dns.GetHostEntry()` for IP addresses, only hostnames:

```
IPEndPoint endPoint = new IPEndPoint("192.168.1.152", 80);
```

Second, your request is not formatted correctly.  You are missing the `Host` header (required in HTTP 1.1), and you are missing a final `\r\n` at the end of the request:

```
byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(@"GET /MyWebServer HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: 192.168.1.152\r\n\r\n");
```

That being said, you really should be using [`HttpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx) or [`HttpClient`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.aspx) instead of using `NetworkStream` directly, eg:

```
using (WebRequest Request = new WebRequest.Create("http://192.168.1.152/MyWebServer"))
{
    WebResponse Response = Request.GetResponse();
    // use Response as needed...
}
```

```
using (HttpClient Client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://192.168.1.152/");
    HttpResponseMessage Response = await Client.GetAsync("MyWebServer");
    // use Response as needed...
}
```

Comment: I'll try what you recommended and report back tomorrow.  The reason I'm not using a WebRequest is that I'm running this using the microframework so I want a very small foot print.  Thanks.